# Matplotlib histogram where each bin is colored by frequency of additional parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I have

```
data = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'c')]
```

such that there are two properties for each datapoint:

```
x, y = zip(*data)
```

I can display `x` in a histogram, ala:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
bins = [1, 2, 3]; f = [3, 2, 4]`.
```

Then, using the second property,

```
y = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

each bin from the original histogram has frequency information for the secondary parameter:

```
bins[0] = {'a': 2, 'b': 1}
bins[1] = {'a': 1, 'b': 1}
bins[2] = {'b': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Using `matplotlib`, I can create the basic histogram of `x`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x, 3)
```

Is there a clever way to iterate over the patches, perhaps, to break them up into appropriately sized rectangles that reflect the additional information, `y`?

In the example, if I wanted `'a'` to be *red*, `'b'` to be **green** and `'c'` to be ***blue***, then first bin (x = 1) would be *two-thirds red* and **one-third green**, the second bin (x = 2) would be *half red* and **half green** and the final bin (x = 3) would be **one-fourth green** and ***three-fourths blue***.

[Example illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x7QJ.png)

Comment: Do [these examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_multihist.html) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is not quite a complete answer, but if you were to reformat your data, then you could use some built-in functionality of `hist` to avoid having to code everything up by hand.

For example, you might make list which contains all of the `x` values with `y` value equal to `'a'`, another where `y = 'b'`, and finally, one where `y = 'c'`. You can then stack those lists into another list, and call `hist` on that data, with `stacked = True`.

See http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html (5th panel down) for an illustration.